# Render Android MediaCodec output on two views for VR Headset compatibility

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, textureview, virtual-reality

What I know so far is that I need to use a SurfaceTexture that can be rendered on two TextureViews simultaneously.
So it will be: 
MediaCodec -> SurfaceTexture -> 2x TextureViews

But how do I get a SurfaceTexture programmaticly to be used in the MediaCodec? As far as I know a new SurfaceTexture is created for every TextureView, so if I have two TextureViews in my activity, I will get two TextureViews!? Thats one to much... ;)

Or is there any other way to render the MediaCodec Output to a screen twice?

Comment: have you seen https://github.com/google/grafika sample ?

Comment: yes. But how to get just one TextureView?

Answer (score 3):

Do you actually require two TextureViews, or is that just for convenience?

You could, for example, have a single SurfaceView or TextureView that covers the entire screen, and then just render on the left and right sides with GLES.  With the video output in a SurfaceTexture, you can render it however you like.  The "texture from camera" activity in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) demonstrates various ways to manipulate image from a video source.

If you really want two TextureViews, you can have them.  Use a single EGL context for the SurfaceTexture and both TextureViews, and just switch between EGL surfaces with `eglMakeCurrent()` when it's time to render.

In any event, you should be creating your own SurfaceTexture to receive the video, not using one that comes from a TextureView -- see e.g. [this bit of code](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/TextureFromCameraActivity.java#L530).

Comment: No I don't need two TextureViews. The only thing I need is the MediaCodec Output on both sides of the screen. I thought it would be the easiest way to achieve it with two TextureViews.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it running. Can you provide some sourcecode to render the left and right side with GLES!?